# VB.NET datarow will not perform comparison

Tags: vb.net, dataset, comparison, datarow

I have a table with 2 column

```
+------+------+
| Col1 | Col2 |
+------+------+
| 1000 |    2 |
| 1000 |    4 |
| 1001 |    6 |
| 1002 |    8 |
+------+------+
```

I'm trying to do a comparison between the datarow column value of the current row with the previous datarow column value in col1 and if they are the same value return the value of the col2 of that current row

here is my code:

```
if myDataRow.Item("Col1") = preVal Then
id = myDataRow.Item("Col2").ToString()
end if

preVal = -1
preVal = myDataRow.Item("Col1").ToString
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is an extra space at the end of col1 so the values don't match

```
if myDataRow.Item("Col1").ToString().Trim() = preVal Then
id = myDataRow.Item("Col2").ToString()
end if

preVal = -1
preVal = myDataRow.Item("Col1").ToString().Trim()
```